# RichTextBox showing with plain text when added to Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, event-listener

I have a custom Tabs Control I created. It works as a coloured Label for the tab itself and as a Panel to hold the contents. My application reads UI parameters from config files. Take this line as an example from the controls config:

```
RTFBOX=(ID - rtf1) (BOUNDS - 0,0,100,100) (MULTILINE - enable) (FILE - email_rules.rtf)
```

This line tells the application to create an instance of my custom RichTextBoxPlus class and the important thing to take from this is that it is set up to read rich text from the FILE parameter. If I don't add this RichTextBoxPlus to another Control it shows it's rich text formatting absolutely fine.

I have another config that reads actions at runtime, this can be simple stuff like telling a Button created with the controls config that when it is clicked, it should fire off an email using content from a TextBox control. I have an action that pairs controls to each tab in the Tabs custom control. For example:

```
ADDTOTABS=(OBJECT - tabsControl1) (CONTROLS - panel1, panel2)
```

This finds `tabsControl1` and adds `panel1` to the 1st tab and `panel2` to the 2nd tab. In this example, Panels are being added to each tab instead of individual controls as the Panels could hold multiple controls, handled at runtime through the ADDTOPANEL action.

```
ADDTOPANEL=(OBJECT - rtf1) (TARGET - panel1) (TRIGGER - onload)
```

So the `rtf1` instance of `RichTextBoxPlus` is added to `panel1` which is then added to the respective `Panel` of the `Tabs` control's 1st tab.

What I have found is rtf1 displays with rich text formatting absolutely fine if added to panel1 but not adding panel1 to Tabs.

The ADDTOTABS action executes this method:

```
private void TabContents_Action(Tabs tabpanel, string[] ctrls)
{
    string[] tabs = tabpanel.GetTabNames();
    for(int i = 0; i < tabs.Length; i++)
    {
        Control control = this.Controls.Find(ctrls[i], true).FirstOrDefault();
        tabpanel.SetTaggedObject(control, tabs[i]);
    }
    tabpanel.SetTabActive(tabs[0]);
}
```

The SetTaggedObject method of the Tabs class finds the Panel control that corresponds with the tab name provided:

```
public void SetTaggedObject(Control ctrl, string tab)
{
    Control container = this.Controls.Find(tab, false).FirstOrDefault();
    container.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

Doesn't seem to be anything untoward about this method.

The SetTabActive method of the Tabs class has a little more bulk. This handles changing the appearance of all tabs so that inactive tabs look different to the active tab. It is also hides and shows the panels for each tab based on whether the tab is active.

```
public void SetTabActive(string tab)
{
    LabelPlus activeTab = this.tabs.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(tab));
    List<LabelPlus> inactiveTabs = new List<LabelPlus>(this.tabs.FindAll(x => !x.Name.Equals(tab)));
    activeTab.BackColor = this.ActiveColor;
    activeTab.ForeColor = this.ActiveForeColor;
    string panelName = tab.Remove(tab.Length - this.tabSuffix.Length);
    Panel activeTabPanel = (Panel)this.Controls.Find(panelName, true).FirstOrDefault();
    activeTabPanel.Bounds = new Rectangle(
        new Point(this.tabStart, this.originalLocation.Y + this.TabTotalHeight), this.Size);
    ControlCollection activeTabCtrls = activeTabPanel.Controls;          
    foreach(LabelPlus inactiveTab in inactiveTabs)
    {
        inactiveTab.BackColor = this.InactiveColor;
        inactiveTab.ForeColor = this.InactiveForeColor;
        string inactivePanelName = inactiveTab.Name.Remove(inactiveTab.Name.Length - this.tabSuffix.Length);
        Panel inactiveTabPanel = (Panel)this.Controls.Find(inactivePanelName, true).FirstOrDefault();//
        inactiveTabPanel.Bounds = new Rectangle(
            new Point(this.tabStart, this.originalLocation.Y + this.TabTotalHeight), this.Size);
        ControlCollection inactiveTabControls = inactiveTabPanel.Controls            
foreach (Control ctrl in inactiveTabControls) { ctrl.Location = new Point(0, ctrl.Location.Y); ctrl.Hide(); }
    }
    foreach (Control ctrl in activeTabCtrls)
    { ctrl.Location = new Point(0, ctrl.Location.Y); ctrl.Show(); }
}
```

Not sure but I'd say the issue must be in this method. Any thoughts?

Comment: _"RichTextBox seems to lose its formatting. I think this is due to it being cast as a regular Control"_ -- you are thinking incorrectly. Casting an object has no effect on its state; it simply is a means of reinterpreting the reference you have. If you want an answer, please edit your question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, with a precise explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: "How can I adjust my code to allow all UserControls to be passed to the Event Handler without being cast generically?" ... Pass them as Objects ....

Comment: Hi @Peter I have rewrote the question to try and provide more clarity on how the application works and what is at fault